# Rails 4 - in_time_zone unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone, utc

I am using Rails 4 trying to work with the in_time_zone helper, and can't understand the weird behavior.

When converting my timestamp to UTC in localhost (or from the console), everything works as expected:

```
"2016-12-05 10:00 pm".to_time.in_time_zone("UTC)
=> 2016-12-06 05:00:00 UTC # this is the correct utc time
```

However, on my production site, it returns an incorrect time.

```
"2016-12-05 10:00 pm".to_time.in_time_zone("UTC)
=> 2016-12-05 22:00:00 UTC # this is incorrect
```

Not sure how this is possible.. UTC should be UTC regardless. Any help understanding why this is happening would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the software what time zone you're converting *from*, not just *to*. Since you don't, it assumes that it should convert from the system time to UTC. As it happens, it appears that the system clock on your production server is *already* in UTC, so it doesn't change the time at all.

Since you seem to be in UTC-7, I'm guessing you're on the west coast of the United States, so you might use code like this:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['America/Los_Angeles'].parse("2016-12-05 10:00 pm").utc
```